# Сортировка массива времен

Tags: php

Есть возможность отсортировать массив времен вида:

```
[
    '22:45',
    '9:15',
    '10:31'
]
```

Простыми способами, или только через `uasort()` со своим методом сортировки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.natsort.php)

> Эта функция реализует алгоритм сортировки, при котором порядок
>   буквенно-цифровых строк будет привычным для человека. Такой алгоритм
>   называется "natural ordering".

```
$a = [
    '22:45',
    '9:15',
    '10:31'
];
natsort($a);
print_r($a);

Array
(
    [1] => 9:15
    [2] => 10:31
    [0] => 22:45
)
```